# While loop hangs when decrement variable is set in PHP

Tags: php

the while loop hangs with the decrement variable ($j--) set after the echo command..

```
$j = 10;
while($j>-10)
{      
  if($j==0)continue;
  echo (10/$j) . "<br>";
  $j--;
}
```

but works well when set before if statement

```
$j = 10;
    while($j>-10)
    {   
      $j--;   
      if($j==0)continue;
      echo (10/$j) . "<br>";

    }
```

Can anyone explain pls?

Answer (score 7):

When `$j==0` it skips the rest of the code in the loop because of the `continue` so it never gets to the `$j--` in the first code.

This means that `$j` will never get below 0 and the loop will never finish.

As in the second code it will always decrements it before the test, it will eventually get to -10.

Try adding

```
echo $j.PHP_EOL;
```

as the first line in the loop (assuming you are using the CLI version) to see what is happening.

Another slightly different version of your code can be used to ONLY avoid the `echo` when `$j` is 0, instead of doing the `continue`...

```
$j = 10;
while($j>-10)
{
    if($j != 0)  {
        echo (10/$j) . "<br>";
    }
    $j--;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nigel. Understood now. Also, It means I can never print 10/10 output even with do while loop. right?

Comment: You can - the easiest way of doing that it to start `$j` at 11, so the first loop it decrements `$j` to 10.

Comment: yeah. that would do. but in real world, if the user inputs 10 and wants to output the 10/10, not possible I guess. But echo (10/$j) . "<br>"; before the do statement would do. Thanks for the clarification anyways.

Comment: I've added another code version to the answer, this doesn't use continue.

Comment: That is great. Thanks for the clean solution.